# Figuring out the IP address of a service for dockerized Consul

Tags: docker, kubernetes, consul

I am building a microservices based application and would like to use Consul as service registry. All in all I have three scenarios:

- All the services run on the host.
- All the services run on the host, but Consul runs in Docker.
- All the services and Consul run in Docker.

Now I have the problem of how to register the services with their IP address, because I need to figure out their IP address so that it is reachable by Consul (e.g., for the health checks):

- If everything runs on the same host, it's pretty easy: Simply use `127.0.0.1`, and you're done.
- If everything (including Consul) runs in Docker, I could use `hostname -i` from within the Docker containers to figure out their external IP and hand it over to Consul. This works, but I wonder if there is  a better way to solve this? (Ideally, the solution should also work in the same way on Kubernetes.)
- If the services run on the host, but Consul runs in Docker, right now I am missing any idea at all. Basically, Consul requires the host's IP address to be able to talk to the services, but I can only detect this from within the Consul container (by resolving `host.docker.internal`). But first, this does not work from externally, and second it only works for Docker for Mac / Windows, not e.g. with Kubernetes.

How could I solve these issues?

PS: I would like to avoid using a container such as `registrator` by Gliderlabs, since I have doubts how well this works on Kubernetes, and also it won't help with the mixed Docker / host scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Kubernetes, you might start by checking whether its [built-in service registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) meets your needs.  There's generally not a direct path to reach a pod via its node's host's IP address, so the setup you describe won't really work well.  (I might consider Consul for a key/value store but I wouldn't reach for it as a service registry in Kubernetes land.)

In plain multi-host Docker land, this is one of the few situations I've found where host networking is appropriate.  Start Consul with `--net host` or an equivalent option in Docker Compose or another orchestration tool.  Then Consul will believe "its" IP address is the host's, and if you have automated TCP probes of well-known ports, you can search every service that's running on the host and discover *e.g.* a MySQL service on port 3306, whether running in a container or natively on the host.

With this setup, `servicename.service.consul` will resolve to some physical-host IP address.  If you have a Docker container pointing at its current host for DNS service, then that will route a service to some host, maybe the same one, but this has worked reliably for me in the past.

Note that the relevant hostnames will be different in different environments: `servicename.service.consul` for a Consul-based setup, `servicename.namespacename.svc.cluster.local` in Kubernetes, maybe `localhost` in a developer-desktop environment.  You need to make sure this is configurable, most straightforwardly via an environment variable.